# AngularJS routing pulling main page content even when user not logged in

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I made a simple app that have a login function using AngularJS. I used routing and on resolve i put some logic to check if user is logged in and then only proceed accordingly. I have everything working fine, the problem is, when i am not logged in, if i browse to */home* it doesn't load the *main.html* page(that's how it's supposed to be) but a GET request gets called and that returns content of *main.html* in console.
My code looks like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        resolve:{
            test: function($http, $q,$location){
                var defer = $q.defer();
                //checks if user is logged and returns boolean 
                $http.post('login/getLoggedUser', {}, {}).success(function(data){
                    if(!data.logged){
                        defer.resolve(data);
                        $location.url('/');
                    }
                    else{
                        defer.resolve(data);
                        $location.url('/home')
                    }
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
    })
        .when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve:{
                test: function($http, $q,$location){                        
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $http.post('login/getLoggedUser', {}, {}).success(function(data){
                        if(data.logged){
                            defer.resolve(data);
                            $location.url('/home');
                        }
                        else{
                            defer.resolve(data);
                            $location.url('/')
                        }
                    });
                    return defer.promise;
                }
            },
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

When i direct to /home, GET http:/localhost:8080/an-grails/partials/main.html is called in console which contains the content of main page. How do i disable this call? Is there any other method to do this? I read documentation on *AngularJS official page* and also watched few videos of *Egghead.io* about resolve and got idea that controller and template gets loaded only after resolve is processed, So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to manage rights in your different routes is to catch the `$routeChangeStart`  which is fired by the `$route` service everytime the route is changed.

With this, you can access the actual route and the next one. This object is the same that you register with `$routeProvider.when()`. You just have to add a boolean and compare this boolean with the actual user status.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if (next.loggedOnly && !user.isLogged()) {
        // You should implement a isLogged method to test if the user is logged
        $location.replace();
        // This prevent a redirect loop when going back in the browser
        return $location.path("/");
    }
}
```

And inside your route declaration use :

```
 $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        loggedOnly: true
 });
```